# 18.04 Can't see ssid of created wifi hotspot in android device

Tags: networking, 18.04, android

I created wifi hotspot in wifi settings by turning hotspot on and can't see the newly created ssid on my android smartphone. It just doesn't find anything. Does anyone have similar problem? I thought it may be hardware issue but tried it in Windows and it works fine so it should be possible.

Also there is nothing to setup, everything is created automatically.

Comment: I am trying to share my cable ethernet connection via wifi.

Comment: Can you manually add the SSID from Andriod's Wi-Fi settings?

Comment: I don't think so or at least I didn't find such option. I finally found settings for wifi hotspot and tried to change modes, people suggested it should be in "client" mode, that my wifi adapter isn't maybe capable of ad-hoc mode but when I try to create hotspot this way it will show error "activation of the network failed", it is really strange for me when in windows I have no problem with it at all